# How to calculate the number of occurrences between data in excel?

Tags: python, excel, csv, statistics

I have a huge CSV table of thousands of data, I want to make a table of number of occurrence of two elements together divided by how many that element presented
[[image: CSV data1]

Like **Bitcoin** appeared 8 times in this rows with 2 times with **API** so the relation between bitcoin to **API**: is that **API** always exists with bitcoin so the value of **API** appearing with bitcoin is 1 and bitcoin appearing with API is 1/4.
I want something looks like this in the end

[image]

How I can do it with python or any other tool?

This is sample of file

[sample of the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13tRaLDbz2M7bcw7Y9nbddKM7UZ7CrzJ6-DRxik9636I/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This would be a fun project.  I think you'd have to do it in two passes.  One would accumulate a dictionary mapping each word to the list of words it appeared with (with duplicates).  After that, you'd know the size of the 2D matrix to create.  A pass through that dictionary would let you fill in the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, I think, does do the job.  I typed your spreadsheet into a csv by hand (would have been nice to be able to cut and paste), and the results seem reasonable.

```
import itertools
import csv
import numpy as np

words = {}
for row in open('input.csv'):
    parts = row.rstrip().split(',')
    for a,b in itertools.combinations(parts,2):
        if a not in words:
            words[a] = [b]
        else:
            words[a].append( b )
        if b not in words:
            words[b] = [a]
        else:
            words[b].append( a )

print(words)
size = len(words)
keys = list(words.keys())
track = np.zeros((size,size))

for i,k in enumerate(keys):
    track[i,i] = len(words[k])
    for j in words[k]:
        track[i,keys.index(j)] += 1
        track[keys.index(j),i] += 1

print(keys)

# Scale to [0,1].

for row in range(track.shape[0]):
    track[row,:] /= track[row,row]

# Create a csv with the results.

fout = open('corresp.csv','w')
print( ','.join([' ']+keys), file=fout )
for row in range(track.shape[0]):
    print( keys[row], file=fout, end=',')
    print( ','.join(f"{track[row,i]}" for i in range(track.shape[1])), file=fout )
```

Here's the first few lines of the result:

```
 ,API,Backend Development,Bitcoin,Docker,Article Rewriting,Article writing,Blockchain,Content Writing,Ghostwriting,Android,Ethereum,PHP,React.js,C Programming,C++ Programming,ASIC,Digital ASIC Coding,Embedded Software,Article Writing,Blog,Copy Typing,Affiliate Marketing,Brand Marketing,Bulk Marketing,Sales,BlockChain,Business Strategy,Non-fungible Tokens,Technical Writing,.NET,Arduino,Software Architecture,Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE),C# Programming,Ada programming,Programming,Haskell,Rust,Algorithm,Java,Mathematics,Machine Learning (ML),Matlab and Mathematica,Data Entry,HTML,Circuit Designs,Embedded Systems,Electronics,Microcontroller, C++ Programming,Python
API,1.0,0.14285714285714285,0.5714285714285714,0.14285714285714285,0.0,0.0,0.2857142857142857,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.14285714285714285,0.0,0.14285714285714285,0.2857142857142857,0.2857142857142857,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Backend Development,0.6666666666666666,1.0,0.6666666666666666,0.6666666666666666,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Bitcoin,0.21052631578947367,0.05263157894736842,1.0,0.05263157894736842,0.0,0.0,0.2631578947368421,0.0,0.0,0.05263157894736842,0.10526315789473684,0.10526315789473684,0.05263157894736842,0.15789473684210525,0.21052631578947367,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.0,0.0,0.05263157894736842,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.05263157894736842,0.05263157894736842,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Docker,0.6666666666666666,0.6666666666666666,0.6666666666666666,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I can't thank enough for your efforts!! That really helped me so much! Now I can play with it with machine learnings algorithms. If you are interested in the data I can share with you the sheet (it is a personal sheet) and the scrapping code! thank you so much!

Comment: No, but I am curious: are these keywords extracted from job postings?

Comment: yes they are extracted from freelancer.com

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at this by creating a pivot table in Excel for every combination of columns there are: AB AC, AD, BC, BD, CD and putting the unique entries from the first column, eg A, in the rows and the unique entries from the second, eg B, in the column and then putting column A in the values area, I find all matches and the count of all matches

This is a clunky method but I note from the Python based method that has been submitted, my answer is essentially no more or less clunky than that!